# metadata api code to fetch the active status of process flows

Tags: metadata-api, visual-flows

CODE:

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
MetadataService.FlowDefinition flow = 
    (MetadataService.FlowDefinition) 
        service.readMetadata('FlowDefinition',
                              new String[] {'test_flow-1' }).getRecords([0];
System.debug('Versionnumber ' + flow.activeVersionNumber);
```

kindly let me know what is wrong in my above code in salesforce?

ERROR:

> Incompatible types since an instance of MetadataService.Metadata is never an instance of MetadataService.FlowDefinition

My main aim is to deactivate the flow ,according to the salesforce docs
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flowdefinition.htm, we need to get the *activeVersionNumber* field of the *FlowDefinition* and set it to 0 to deactivate it.

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking to review the code or you are getting any errors? If you are getting errors, to be able to help, you need to post your error trace as well.

Comment: yeah error I am getting is this that IncompatibleType Metadata class with FlowDefinition. Kindly help.

Comment: Exact error:----------------------------------------------------------Incompatible types since an instance of MetadataService.Metadata is never an instance of MetadataService.FlowDefinition

Comment: Can you please [**edit**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/217735/edit) your original post and update it with the exception?

Comment: yeah Jayant updated it. Thnx.

Comment: Seems like you are using financial force apis, do you have all necessary classes associated with it?

Comment: yeah correct.....necessary classes i think i have,whatever is there in the above code,that much only ,i have. apart from this anything else ,I am not aware of. Any help would be appreciated.